# Macro to split up text into different rows depending on a keyword

Tags: excel, vba

I have a varying number of rows of text which I paste into excel like those two below. The content will vary slightly but the overall structure will stay the same:

Now I need to split these up and would therefore like a macro which searches for the word "maturity" and selects this word and all the text on the right side of the word and moves it one cell to the right.

I tried splitting it up via text to row, but the position of the word varies and splitting it up via space or comma destroys the rest of the data.

example:

```
1/ Worst Of Put K UN, WS UQ, XYZ YX maturity 22May2019, 80% strike, size q€7M (€ quanto), BID 

2/ Worst Of Put xyz xy, TSLA UQ, KK BK maturity 20Nov2021, 100% strike, size €3.5M (€ quanto), BID
```

the macro should keep `"2/ Worst Of Put xyz xy, TSLA UQ, KK BK"` in one cell and move `"maturity 20Nov2021, 100% strike, size €3.5M (€ quanto), BID"` one cell to the right.

Many thanks for the help,
Ragnar

Answer (score 1):

Step 1) Do a Find/Replace on your data.  Find `maturity`, replace with `~maturity`. [Note: This assumes you won't have `~` anywhere in the strings. Use another character if you have `~` somewhere.]

Step 2) Highlight your data, go to Text to Columns, and split on a delimiter `~`

[image]